# Increment string value

Tags: php, string, operator-keyword, varchar

I have my app ID number in this format 003002345 (Varchar) I want to 1 to the ID to get to the next ID 003002346 .
How should I do since the datatype is Varchar

Comment: Tags [tag:php] and [tag:varchar] are in opposition. Do you want to do it in PHP (string), or in a database (varchar)? Only one of those tags is relevant. (If it is all the same to you, it is trivially easy in PHP.) If database, please also tag with specific database engine.

Comment: It depends on how they're added to the database. But you might not want to trust the last row is the higher one, and in which case you'll have to get them all, sort, and get the last one (or first depending on your sort method). It sounds like you want an auto increment column to me but without more info it's impossible to tell

Comment: you have to get last inserted app id and sum 1 then or use ++ to add 1 in php if in that colom no an other value charaters .

Comment: @RakeshkumarOad last inserted might not be the highest. This is not an auto increment field it's a varchar. Rows could have been updated anywhere, or inserted with the varchar varying in order to the previous ones.

Answer (score 0):

You could also type cast your variable to an int via PHP, increment with 1 and convert back to the desired format.

Comment: I presumed their issue was finding the last value in the DB in the first place as it's varchar.

Comment: But it was tagged as PHP as well, so it could be fetching a varchar from the DB via PHP ;)

Comment: Yes, but "which" varchar do you fetch from the DB? Casting after the fact is not the issue, getting the highest is the issue I think - how to get highest with SQL query or fetch all and in PHP sort and get highest.  TBH the DB design seems bad and sounds like an auto increment ID would be better